# JS filter not working for js variable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

In my lightning controller, I'm trying to filter dynamically value based on user input.

when I get the value in js variable and filter based on that it's not working. whereas when I hard code the filter it's working.

```
var searchValue = component.get('v.SearchTerm');
console.log('>>> searchValue ... '+searchValue);
var fValues = component.get('v.SearchResults');
// Not working
console.log('>>> search resultssssss..... '+fValues.filter(c => c.picklistName.startsWith(searchValue)));
// working
console.log('>>> search resultssssss hard coded..... '+fValues.filter(c => c.picklistName.startsWith('As')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.prototype.startsWith is case sensitive. This may be what's confusing you. You may want to convert to a common case before comparing:

```
fValues.filter(row => row.picklistName.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchValue.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: Thanks! IT worked